# CakePHP adding tables to ACL controlled application

Tags: php, cakephp, acl

Sorry if this is a noob question, I'm using the [Simple ACL Controlled Application](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/simple-acl-controlled-application.html) tutorial as a boilerplate and need to add (bake) a few more tables.  If I create a new table then run "cake bake all" from the console, how would I go about updating the ACL as well, I believe I should only need to update the acos table, could be wrong?  Is there a command I should use after the new models, views and controllers are generated?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT : I'm using the [AclExtras](https://github.com/markstory/acl_extras/tree/2.0) plugin to to input all of my controllers and actions into the Acl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sync up your ACO using AclExtras, you would run something like this at the command line:

```
php "/cake/lib/Cake/Console/cake.php" AclExtras.AclExtras aco_sync
```